Flutter WebView not working in iOS but works fine in Android
I'm developing a Flutter app (with GetX) where I need WebView somewhere. I'm sharing my code below which works perfectly for Android devices but not in iOS simulator. I still couldn't detect the problem.
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(unregistered_view_type, A UIKitView widget is trying to create a PlatformView with an unregistered type: < plugins.flutter.io/webview >, If you are the author of the PlatformView, make sure registerViewFactory is invoked.
class VirtualCardController extends GetxController {

/* other codes */

late final WebViewController controller;

/* other codes */

@override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();

    var params = const PlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams();

    if (WebViewPlatform.instance is WebKitWebViewPlatform) {
      params = WebKitWebViewControllerCreationParams.fromPlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams(params);
    } else if (WebViewPlatform.instance is AndroidWebViewPlatform) {
      params = AndroidWebViewControllerCreationParams.fromPlatformWebViewControllerCreationParams(params);
    }

    controller = WebViewController.fromPlatformCreationParams(params);
  }

  void _loadWebView(String url) {
    // Ensure the URL has a scheme
    if (url.isEmpty) {
      url = 'https://www.google.com/';
    } else if (!url.startsWith('https://') && !url.startsWith('http://')) {
      url = 'https://$url';
    }

    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {},
          onPageStarted: (String url) {},
          onPageFinished: (String url) {},
          onHttpError: (HttpResponseError error) {},
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(url)).then((_) {
        isLoading.value = false;
      });
  }

/* other codes */

}

Note that I have added these in pubspec.yaml:

webview_flutter: ^4.8.0
webview_flutter_android: ^3.16.4
webview_flutter_wkwebview: ^3.14.0


Is there any error logs in ios? please share them.

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(unregistered_view_type, A UIKitView widget is trying to create a PlatformView with an unregistered type: < plugins.flutter.io/webview >, If you are the author of the PlatformView, make sure registerViewFactory is invoked.
